# How to Shadow an Entire Package in Common Lisp

Tags: package, common-lisp, shadow

Common Lisp provides the :shadow clause to disable inheritance of package names you don't want to use. But how to shadow an entire package of names?

Here's my basic setup:

```
#-cl-ppcre (ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)
#-iterate (progn (ql:quickload :iterate) (push :iterate *features*))
#-rutilsx (progn (ql:quickload :rutilsx) (push :rutilsx *features*))

(defpackage :concepts
  (:use :cl :cl-ppcre :iterate :rutilsx)
  (:shadow :iter)  ;error
  (:nicknames :con))
```

but this generates name conflicts.

The problem is that :rutilsx includes the :iter package, which I'd like to disable, so I can use :iterate instead. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I would refrain from using `:use`: https://gist.github.com/phoe/2b63f33a2a4727a437403eceb7a6b4a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the conflict in favour of `iterate` by doing a `:shadowing-import-from` of the relevant symbols from there, which should be a manageable number.

Another option is to `:use` the only the specific `rutils` packages that you need.

Finally, you could use package prefixes for most things (maybe with package-local-nicknames) and only explicitly import those symbols that would be unwieldy without package prefix.  This also makes it easier to see where a symbol comes from.

Comment: With regard to the 2nd approach, after quickloading how would you get a list of all the packages that are in the aggregate package :rutils?

Comment: I would look at the source file (packages.lisp).